I can't define default text as bold in Neovim
I can't define default text as bold in Neovim
hi  normal          ctermfg=grey        cterm=bold
hi  function        ctermfg=blue        cterm=bold

Etc...
Same for italic. It works with "comment", "function", etc.. With anything. But never with "normal".
